# Skip print preview with .print()

Tags: html

I have a coffee program made with jquery and HTML that is now working perfectly.

I just want to skip the need to press the print button after pressing placing order. After clicking place order I would like it to just print 2 copies.

The current code for the printing process:

```
 alert_toast("Data successfully saved.",'success')
      setTimeout(function(){
           var nw = window.open('../receipt.php?id='+resp,"_blank","width=900,height=600")
           setTimeout(function(){
                 nw.print()
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     nw.close()
                     location.reload()
                 },500)
            },500)
       },500)
```

Code for Receipt.php

```
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';
$order = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM orders where id = {$_GET['id']}");
foreach($order->fetch_array() as $k => $v){
$$k= $v;
}
$items = $conn->query("SELECT o.*,p.name FROM order_items o inner join products p on p.id = o.product_id where o.order_id = $id ");
?>

<style>
.flex{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.w-50{
    width: 50%;
}
.text-center{
    text-align:center;
}
.text-right{
    text-align:right;
}
table.wborder{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.wborder>tbody>tr, table.wborder>tbody>tr>td{
    border:1px solid;
}
p{
    margin:unset;
}

</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<p class="text-center"><b><?php echo $amount_tendered > 0 ? 
"Receipt" : "Bill" ?></b></p>
<hr>
<div class="flex">
    <div class="w-100">
        <?php if($amount_tendered > 0): ?>
        <p><b>Cafe 365 - Thank you for your Order!</b></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <p><b><?php $now = new DateTime();
 echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?></b></p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<p><b>Order List</b></p>
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>QTY</b></td>
            <td><b>Order</b></td>
            <td class="text-right"><b>Amount</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        while($row = $items->fetch_assoc()):
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['qty'] ?></td>
            <td><p><?php echo $row['name'] ?></p><?php 
if($row['qty'] > 0): ?><small>(R<?php echo 
number_format($row['price'],2) ?>)</small> <?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="text-right">R<?php echo 
number_format($row['amount'],2) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Total Amount</b></td>
            <td class="text-right"><b>R<?php echo 
number_format($total_amount,2) ?></b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if($amount_tendered > 0): ?>


    
    <?php endif; ?>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>

</div>
```

I am not sure how to change this. Still learning

Comment: The print code should be placed inside `receipt.php` not here

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Hi I have updated my code to show receipt.php

Comment: I don't think you can skip print preview without a browser extension. If that was possible, rest assured that your printer tray would be full of spam from dubious sites.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález may i ask if you know how i may get it to print 2 copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by enabling Kiosk mode on chrome

editing the chrome shortcut on the machine and adding  --kiosk --kiosk-printing after the chrome.exe"

it now prints immediately

Answer (score 0):

First part of your codes seems to be in another page and after placing the order, you are opening a new window to show the receipt. correct? If you want to print the receipt then you need to write the printing code inside the `receipt.php` not in the current file. So inside the `receipt.php` you can run the print on page load:

```
<body onload="window.print()">
```

Footnote: your receipt.php file is missing the body tag. If you dont want to use body tag for a reason, you can also initiate the print on page load like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() { window.print(); }
</script>
```

Comment: I edited my question with the receipt.php code if that helps :)

Comment: I tried the body onload and the script separately it still opens a print preview screen and it also does it twice. I assume since the original code is still in the top file

Comment: I was able to sort the print preview problem. May i ask if you know how i may get it to print 2 copies?